# Target elements with single child AND no text nodes outside that child, using jQuery

Tags: jquery, children, textnode

Using jQuery, I'm trying to target all paragraph elements that only contain a child anchor element (as a direct descendent) AND that have no text nodes outside of that child element, eg:

```
<p><a href="http://...">Some link</a></p>
```

I've tried jQuery's `only-child` selector, but text nodes obviously aren't treated as child elements. I've also looked at `contents()` and presume I could target anchor elements whose opening tag is the first node. However, on the latter, the site I'm building is a blog that others will be writing for using a CMS and so I can't ensure they won't begin a regular paragraph with a link, which would add unwanted styling.

I'm relatively new to jQuery - about one month. Just so you know...

Thanks!

Comment: you could try using `.text().length`
it return the length of a text inside an element and ignores HTML snippets (such as `"<i>"`).
Combine this with a `$.each` loop and you can check every child node for its `text().length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mak0Ls5r/)

```
$('p').filter(function() {
  return ( 1 === $(this).find('*').length && 1 === $(this).find('a').length && $(this).text() === $(this).find('a').text() );
});
```

Edit: I didnt know about the `:only-child` selector in the first place. With it, even cleaner:

```
$('p').has('a:only-child').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('a').text() === $(this).text();                  
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex! This is exactly what I'm looking for. Reading through it a few times, it seems like such a clear, logical solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by zeropublix comment:

```
$("p").has("a:only-child").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find("a").text() === $(this).text();                  
});
```

You could also prototype it to make your code cleaner:

```
$.fn.onlyChild = function(child) {
   return this.has(child + ":only-child").filter(function() {
        return $(this).find(child).text() === $(this).text();                  
    });
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpr3xja4/1/).

Comment: Many thanks, Anders. I need to grasp loops so will have a play around with this too. Cheers